# design functionality React native

Tags: react-native

I want user profile pic in half on modal and half on outside of modal

i have tried this

```
                                    height: PROFILE_DIAMETER,
                                    width: PROFILE_DIAMETER,
                                    borderRadius: PROFILE_DIAMETER / 2,
                                    marginLeft: 20,
                                    top: -20,
                                    flex: 0,
                                    resizeMode: 'cover',
                                    overflow: 'hidden',
                                    transform: [{translateY: translateImageY()}, {scale: imgScale()}, {translateX: translateImageX()}]
                                }}
```

[want to achieve this design functionality to react-native](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWM9c.png)

Comment: Hi, it might be helpful if you said what the problem is -- what's *not* working -- or showed a screenshot. It would also be helpful if you posted most code so that folks could see what the context of this image is that might be impacting the style.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Image style={{width: '100%', zIndex: -1}} source={require('../assets/capa.png')} />
    <View style={{
        width: '90%',
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        alignSelf: 'center',
        borderRadius: 10,
        paddingBottom: 20
    }}>
        <View style={{
            marginTop: -100
        }}>
            <Avatar
                rounded
                size='xlarge'
                containerStyle={{ alignSelf: "center", marginTop: 20 }}
                overlayContainerStyle={{
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    borderColor: '#00a9cf',
                    backgroundColor: 'white'
                }}
                source={{
                    uri:
                        'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/adhamdannaway/128.jpg',
                }}
            />
            <Text style={{ color: '#383941', fontSize: 22, alignSelf: "center", fontFamily: 'PTSans-Bold' }}>{this.state.name}</Text>
            <Text style={{ color: '#79787b', fontSize: 15, alignSelf: "center", fontFamily: 'PTSans-Italic' }}>{this.state.profession}</Text>
        </View>
    </View>
```

Observe the image with zindex -1 and the view containing the avatar with the negative marginTop